# Biggest (or large) rectangle in a polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

I need an *efficient* method to construct a (hyper)rectangle inside a polytope with a lot of dimensions (say $100 < d < 1000$). Ideally I'd want the biggest possible rectangle, but as I don't think this is possible, I want to see if anyone can think of a better way than my method, which is finding the Chebyshev sphere of the polytope and putting a cube inside it. Obviously, this makes very small rectangles (ratio of cube volume to polytope volume), especially in high dimensions.

Comment: This is already nontrivial in 2D: Knauer, Christian, Lena Schlipf, Jens M. Schmidt, and Hans Raj Tiwary. "Largest inscribed rectangles in convex polygons." *Journal of Discrete Algorithms* 13 (2012): 78-85.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I realize that. But certainly there has to be something better than what I described!

Comment: This is related, but doesn't seem to answer your question directly: Packer, Asa. "Polynomial-time approximation of largest simplices in V-polytopes." *Discrete Applied Mathematics* 134, no. 1 (2004): 213-237. ([Journal link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X03002269).)

Comment: Incidentally, there is work on finding the largest ellipsoid in a polytope: [ETHZ](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~mpt/2/docs/refguide/mpt/@polytope/getInnerEllipsoid.html).

Comment: Putting a rectangle in that ellipsoid *would* technically be better than my method, but I hope there's something better!